# How do I generate CFG for any sentence using NLTK Python?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

My problem is :

I have a lot of sentences of lot of documents. For every sentence I have to write a CFG using nltk python.

```
grammar1 = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
  S -> NP VP
  VP -> V NP | V NP PP
  PP -> P NP
  V -> "saw" | "ate" | "walked"
  NP -> "John" | "Mary" | "Bob" | Det N | Det N PP
  Det -> "a" | "an" | "the" | "my"
  N -> "man" | "dog" | "cat" | "telescope" | "park"
  P -> "in" | "on" | "by" | "with"
  """)
```

Instead of doing that:

- I want a universal CFG which is applicable to any sentence

or

- I want CFG generated automatically for each sentence.

I’m struck at this. Please help me overcome this.

Comment: Answer to "I want a universal CFG which is applicable to any sentence" = "Not possible".

Comment: Answer to "I want CFG generated automatically for each sentence." = "Perhaps (if you have trained parser)".

Comment: You can either induce the grammatical rules from a treebank of parses or infer new grammatical structures for a new sentence that the parser hasn't seen before.

Comment: Read chapter 8 and 9: http://www.nltk.org/book/

Comment: My idea is we can get tags of every word in the sentence and a tree for a sentence. Based on these two things we can generate a CFG automatically instead of writing for every sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one or more parsed sentences, you can extract a CFG that describes them by calling the method `productions()` on the parsed sentence object (an `nltk.Tree`). Here's an example with the first 10 sentences of the Penn Treebank corpus:

```
>>> ruleset = set(rule for tree in nltk.corpus.treebank.parsed_sents()[:10] 
           for rule in tree.productions())
>>> for rule in ruleset:
        print(rule)

NP -> PRP
NP -> DT JJ NN
VP -> VBN S
ADVP-TMP -> RB
IN -> 'among'
NNP -> 'Corp.'
NP -> PRP$ NN NN NNS
NP-SBJ -> DT
RRC -> ADVP-TMP VP
NNP -> 'Journal'
VP -> VBN NP
...
```

The above will give you 278 rules (including vocabulary items) for those 10 sentences, but it gets better as your sample grows. You can take it from there.

Of course if your sentences aren't parsed yet, you'll first need to parse them.